# Pinging by creating new sockets per each peer

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

I created a small cross-platform app using Qt sockets in C++ (although this is not a C++ or Qt specific question).

The app has a small "ping" feature that tries to connect to a peer and asks for a small challenge (i.e. some custom data sent and some custom data replied) to see if it's alive.

I'm opening one socket per each peer so as soon as the ping starts we have several sockets in `SYN_SENT`.

Is this a proper way to implement a ping-like protocol with challenge? Am I wasting sockets? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Depends on your objective. For example, [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) works by just sending an ICMP request packet, and waiting for an ICMP reply packet. In contrast, a TCP connection is established using a [three-way handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment), and is terminated using a [four-way handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment). So, usually if you are using TCP to transfer one request-reply pair, you are wasting packets.

Comment: "*I'm opening one socket per each peer so as soon as the ping starts we have several sockets in SYN_SENT.*". If you will be using TCP for your ping feature, This how it should be done. You should **not** do connections sequentially (this will be wasting a lot of time, consider if many peers are down for example, and you have to wait for the timeout to occur for each one of them. . .)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your options are:

1. An actual ping (using ICMP echo packets). This has low overhead, but only tells you whether the host is up. And it requires you to handle lost packets, timeouts, and retransmits.
2. A UDP-based protocol. This also has lower kernel overhead, but again you'll be responsible for setting up timeouts, handling lost packets, and retransmits. It has the advantage of allowing you to positively affirm that your program is running on the peer. It can be implemented with only a single socket endpoint no matter how many peers you add. (It is also possible that you could send to multiple peers at once with a broadcast if all are on a local network, or a multicast [complicated set-up required for that].)
3. TCP socket as you're doing now. This is much easier to code, extremely reliable and will automatically provide a timeout (i.e. your `connect` will eventually fail if the peer doesn't respond). It lets you know positively that your peer is there and running your program. Although there is more kernel overhead to this, and you will use one socket endpoint on your host per peer system, I wouldn't call it a significant issue unless you think you'll be having thousands of peers.

So, in the end, you have to judge: If thousands of hosts will be participating and this pinging is going to happen frequently, you may be better off coding up a UDP solution. If the pinging is rare or you don't expect so many peers, I would go the TCP route. (And I wouldn't consider that a "waste of sockets" -- those advantages are why TCP is so commonly used.)

Answer (score 0):

The technique described in the question doesn't really implement `ping` for the connection and doesn't test if the connection itself is alive. The technique only checks that the peer is listening for (and is responsive to) new connections...

What you're describing is more of an "is the server up?" test than a "keep-alive" ping.

If we're discussing "keep-alive" `ping`s, than this technique will fail.

For example, if just the `read` or the `write` aspect of the connection is closed, you wouldn't know. Also, if the connection was closed improperly (i.e., due to an intermediary dropping the connection), this `ping` will not expose the issue.

Most importantly, for some network connections and protocols, you wouldn't be resetting the connection's timeout... so if your peer is checking for connection timeouts, this `ping` won't help.

For a "keep-alive" ping, I would recommend that you implement a protocol specific `ping`.

Make sure that the `ping` is performed within the existing (same) connection and never requires you to open a new connection.